# How to disable death camera and speed up level restarting in Alien Swarm?

Tags: alien-swarm

I have played on ASBI servers where death camera is disabled. Also there is a nice feature when the last player dies you don't have to wait and look at the "Mission Failed" and "Statistics" window but the level restarts quickly, writing with yellow text "Forcing ready..."

How do I create a server from inside a game to have these features enabled?

I have downloaded and installed ASBI's server.dll and h_alien_selection.txt. But this didn't help

Comment: And skip the mandatory post-game rebuking and blame session? Crazytalk!

Comment: Didn't know anyone still played this game

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick restart isn't actually an ASBI feature. Anyone (who is server leader, of course) can do it. Just press F8 as soon as you see the red "Mission Failed" message, and look for a restart button at the bottom.

You can also use this F8-restart anytime during a mission, when you feel like the players who are alive right now are unable to finish the mission.

---

Sadly, death cam is tougher to disable. `asw_marine_death_cam 0` does the trick, however, it requires cheats to be enabled. Moreover, as soon as you disable cheats, it goes back on.

1. How to do it: In main menu open the console, and write there `sv_cheats 1` <kbd>Enter</kbd> `asw_marine_death_cam 0` <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then type `map <the map you want to play>` (e.g. `map as_sci1_bridge`) <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. If you connect to an ASBI server, leave it and then make your own server, it will have some similarities to the ASBI servers, like **no death cam** and changed player collision. Restarting the game removes these effects.
3. You can disable death camera by installing [SourceMod](http://www.sourcemod.net) and using such command:

   sm_cvar asw_marine_death_cam 0

It works both for dedicated server and normal in-game server.

Comment: so cheats will be enabled? What can this lead to? It seam that ASBI servers don't have cheats enabled.

Comment: Yes, cheats will be enabled... this can lead to players using god mode and stuff. This is not recommended anyway. But you could at least show some appreciation for the restart part of the answer.

Comment: Then using cheats is not an option. Also ASBI servers doesn't have cheats enabled. I've noticed that sometimes when I create a server with ASBI dll installed the death cam is turned off. I don't know how this happens, because I don't write anything into console. May be this is because I previously connected to the ASBI server?!